# How long does a Time Machine changes update should take ?! (it takes forever)

Tags: macos, backup, time, time-machine

I've recently upgraded my OS,
and after doing that - my Time Machine takes forever to update... I mean it's more than 24H now, finding changes... more than 370,000 changes found and still counting.

I tried to reboot, hoping it'll continue from where it stopped, but it started over from 0...
[image]

Comment: Open the drive, go to Backups.backupdb & see if it is trying to set up a new computer backup - ie myCompy & myCompy(1)  If not, I think you're going to have to wait it out & see what happens. What did you upgrade your OS from > to?

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you!
I upgraded from High Sierra to Big Sur, and than to Monterey. 
but somehow the back-up after upgrading to Big-Sur was lost, and I have only backup from High-Sierra. very wired. so I don't mind doing a new backup.
the question is - what is faster ?

Comment: Fastest would be erase the drive & start over - Time Machine is probably trying to reformat the backup without losing any data. High Sierra backup was on HFS+, Big Sur & newer must be on APFS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)